# How to get insert values from a table into an array using SQL?

Tags: sql, delphi

```
with dmHospital do
  begin
  qryHospital.SQL.Clear;
  qryHospital.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Patients ') ;
  qryHospital.SQL.Add('WHERE DoctorID = :DoctorID');
  qryHospital.Parameters.ParamByName('DoctorID').Value := StrToInt(sID);
  qryHospital.Open;
  iCount := qryHospital.RecordCount
end;
```

This code displays the values I want to put into the array. However I'm not sure how to cycle through each record and to get each value from the record into the correct array. For example: I want the names from 'PatientName' and the surnames from 'PatientSurname'.
iCount is the array size.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are `dmHospital`, `qryHospital` and how should we know how your SQL database does look like?

Comment: `while not Query.Eof do Query.Next`

Comment: Look up TDataSet.First, .Next and .Eof in the Online Help.  Or just google them.

Comment: Beware that not all TDataSet descendants return a meaningful value for RecordCount and that, with others, causing RecordCount to be evaluated can have a severe impact on performance.

Comment: I am starting to think to extract RTTI functionality from UIB into generic `TDataSet` class helper. Then all the loop looks like this: `var row: record field1:type1; field2:type2; field3:type3; ... end; begin ...qryHospital.Open; for row in qryHospital do begin ... end; qryHospital.Close;` and that is all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must loop from `TDataset` using `While`.

Some sample code:

```
...
var
  fieldCod:TField;
  Str1:String;
  i, Cod:Integer;
begin
  ...
  qryHospital.Open;
  iCount := qryHospital.RecordCount;
  // Create pointer to field
  fieldCod := qryHospital.FieldByName('PatientCode');
  // loop the recordset (while not arrive at end)
  While (not qryHospital.eof) do begin
    // Different modes to access table fields content
    Str1 := qryHospital.FieldByName('PatientName').AsString;
    i := qryHospital.Fields[1].AsInteger;   
    Cod  := fieldCod.AsInteger;     

    // Add the values to your array
    //...

    // Next Record
    qryHospital.Next;
  end;
```

**NOTE**: For better performance, don't use `FieldByName` inside the loop (for big number of records). You can use `Fields[index]` or create a variable out of the loop and reference to fields.

Comment: @germán-estévez-neftalí Thank you!

Comment: one should not using FieldByName inside the loop - it is slow !
create a bunch of TField-type local vars and fill them with FieldByName  BEFORE the loop ///  Also using RecordCount is bad and risky style for SQL indeed

Comment: @GermánEstévez-Neftalí- given that the topicstarter is a total newby, I guess you could add the code samples to both approaches (indices and pointrs vars), otherwise you just repeated my comment adding nothing new.

Comment: @Arioch 'The. Added.